# How to aggregate queries in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document collection that look like the following:

```
{
  name : "tester"
  , activity: [
    {
      gear: "glasses"
      where: "outside"    
    }
    , {
      gear: "hat"
      , where: "inside"
    }
    , {
      gear: "glasses"
      , where: "car"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I query the collection to return only documents with **multiple** activities that contain the value of "gear":"glasses"?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably need an unwind and a sum with a condition.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's possible to do without aggregation framework, if you need full document filtered by your condition:

```
db.collection.find({
    "activity": {$elemMatch: {gear:"glasses"}},
    "activity.1" : {$exists: 1}
})
```

Comment: This seems to work, what does the .1 do?  Is that looking for length of the activity array?  Could I also use .2 to check if it has 2 "glasses"?

Comment: It checks for existance of element with index1

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be ugly with aggregation framework, but it can be done:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$match: {"activity.gear": "glasses"}},
  {$unwind: "$activity"},
  {$group: {
    _id: {_id: "$_id", name: "$name"},
    _count: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["glasses", "$activity.gear"]}, 1, 0]}}
  }},
  {$match: {_count: {$gt: 1}}}
)
```

When analyzing the above query, I would recommend walking through step.  Start with just the "$match", the the "$match" and "$unwind".  And so one.  You will see how each step works.

The response is not the full document.  If you are looking for the full document, include a `$project` step that passes through a dummy activity, and reconstruct the full document on the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
db.collection.find( { activity: { $elemMatch: { gear: "glasses" } } )
```

Comment: This logic is no different than: `db.collection.find({"activity.gear": "glasses"})`.